# Needing help understanding modules over group ring

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $F$ be a field $G$ be a group. We say that a module is **simple** if its only submodules are the zero module and the entire module. From my understanding, the ring $F[G]$ has formal linear combination of the form
$$\sum_{g\in G} \alpha_g \cdot g$$
(where $\alpha_g \in F$) as elements, addition is defined by grouping coefficients of each $g\in G$ and multiplication is defined by
$$h\star \sum_{g\in G} \alpha_g \cdot g =\sum_{g\in G} \alpha_g \cdot hg$$
which extends by linearity.

Now consider $F[G]$ as an $F[G]$ module. The proof below shows that every $F[G]$ is a simple $F[G]$-module$ but I feel like this result is false.

> Suppose $V$ is a nonzero $FG$-submodule of $FG$. Then $V$ is a
> $F$-subspace of $FG$ and thus contains an element of basis of $FG$,
> say $g\in G$. Let $h\in G$. Since $hg^{-1} \in G$ and $V$ is
> $G$-invariant, we have $h = (hg^{-1})\star g \in V$. We have shown that
> $V$ contains every basis element of $FG$ and thus $V = FG$.

Where did I go wrong? What would be an example of $F$ and $G$ such that $F[G]$ is not a simple module over itself?

Comment: "Then $V$ is a F-subspace of $FG$ and thus contains an element of basis of $FG$, say $g \in G$."

This is an incorrect conclusion, in general a subspace of a vector space does not have to contain any element of a chosen basis, e.g $\langle (1,1) \rangle \leq \mathbb{R}^2 = \langle (1,0), (0,1) \rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement my comment, if $G$ is any finite group and $F$ is any field, then we can define the element $e = \sum_{g \in G} g$ (so the $\alpha_g$ are all $1$). Now note that $g e = e$ for all $g \in G$, so the $F$-subspace spanned by $e$ is an $FG$-submodule of $FG$. In particular, $FG$ is not simple for any finite non-trivial $G$.